# How can I plot the following set?

Tags: plotting, regions

I have a question:

How can I plot the following set

$$G:=\{(x,y,z)\in\mathbb{R}^3|x^2+y^2\in[0,4],z\in[0,3]\}?$$

Thank you for your help!

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I hope you will become a regular contributor.  To get started,  1) take the introductory [Tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour) now, 2) when you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge, 3) remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t), and 4) give help too, by answering questions in your areas of expertise.

Comment: Please add the code you have tried.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `RegionPlot3D` for 3D inequalities. You should get a cylinder.

```
RegionPlot3D[
 0 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 4 && 0 <= z <= 3, {x, -3, 3}, {y, -3, 3}, {z, -1,  4}, 
 PlotPoints -> 40]
```

Increase the `PlotPoints` for a better quality mesh.

[image]

Answer (score -1):

My code is:

RegionPlot3D[
 0 <= x^2 + y^2 <= 4 && 0 <= z <= 3, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, {z, 0, 
  3}]

[image: My result!]

Comment: Hi ! Please avoid "thank you"-style comments in the answer-only text boxes.